# Spark in DSE4.5 with EC2MultiRegionSnitch

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I'm have DSE 4.5 cassandra cluster with multi region data center on EC2. So i'm using EC2MultiRegionSnitch which is returning public IP. And I'm trying to create Spark node but logs says "Failed to bind PUBLIC IP:7077. I am sure it is due to EC2MultiRegionSnitch property. I spoke to Amazon guys , as they are not able to help me in binding port with public ip.

Now, I'm not sure which snitch I can use for EC2 multi region data center cluster. (apart from EC2MultiRegionSnitch). So that I'm bind cluster in multi region data center and run Spark.

Can you please suggest ??

Answer (score 0):

The EC2MultiRegionSnitch should be fine for your setup.  I suspect the issue is that port 7077 is not opened in your security group in each data center.

Comment: port is 7077 open in security group. Problem is spark trying to bind 7077 with public ip (which is returned by EC2MultiRegionSnitch). If i setup my cluster in single data region then EC2MultiRegionSnitch is not comming in picture and then spark take private ip for binding 7077 port and then sparks works fine. I think Spark should take private ip for binding port not public ip. How I can fix this issue.

Comment: Yes you are right.  Spark needs to bind to the private IP on 7077 and then the open port 7077 in the security group will handle the nat translation for the nodes in the cluster.  You set the IP with SPARK_MASTER_IP in the spark-env.sh located in /etc/dse/spark/spark-env.sh for packaged installations and install_location/resources/spark/conf/spark-env.sh for tarball installations.

Comment: Yes, I set the private IP with SPARK_MASTER_IP in the spark-env.sh. but still it is picking public IP from EC2MultiRegionSnitch. I think i should log this issue with datastax but I dont know how to log.

Comment: If you are a customer of Datastax you can log it through a support ticket.  If you aren't then I will log it on your behalf.

Comment: I'm not a datastax customer. Please log this issue on my behalf. Thanks for help.

Comment: An internal Jira, DSP-4063 has been created.  I'll watch the Jira and update here with findings.